# Awk replace columns only when regex match and put the result in a file

Tags: regex, awk, replace

I'm learning awk and I want to replace spaces in few columns to replace this :

```
X X X X X X X X LA CROIX-HELLEAN X X
```

with :

```
X X X X X X X X LA_CROIX-HELLEAN X X
```

So I tried :

```
awk '{for(i=j=9; i < NF; i+=1) if ($9=="LA") {$j = $i"_"$(i+1); j++} NF=j-1}1' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

But the result is only keeping the modified lines and I want the unmodified lines too...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: So ... you want to join lines 9 and 10, and reduce your field count by 1?

Comment: yes but reduce the field only for lines that match :)

Comment: You can just use: `awk '{sub(/ LA /, " LA_")} 1' file`

Comment: The `1` at the end should print every line. What are your criteria for "lines that match"? Can you provide an example of input that *isn't* turning into the output that you want?

Comment: In fact, the $9 represents the geographical position and I've got some cities which contains spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will merge fields 9 and 10...

```
awk '{$9=$9"_"$10; for(i=10;i<NF;i++) $i=$(i+1); NF-- } 1'
```

If some of your lines do not require the merge, then perhaps they have the wrong number of fields:

```
$ s=$'X X X X X X X X LA CROIX-HELLEAN X X\nX X X X X X X X TORONTO X X'
$ awk 'NF==12 {$9=$9"_"$10; for(i=10;i<NF;i++) $i=$(i+1); NF-- } 1' <<< "$s"
X X X X X X X X LA_CROIX-HELLEAN X X
X X X X X X X X TORONTO X X
```

Or, if some of your `$9` fields contain MORE than one space, you might want a more open-ended reduction:

```
$ s=$'X X X X X X X X LA CROIX-HELLEAN X X\nX X X X X X X X TORONTO X X\nX X X X X X X X ONE TWO THREE X X'
$ awk '{while (NF>11) {$9=$9"_"$10; for(i=10;i<NF;i++) $i=$(i+1); NF-- }} 1' <<< "$s"
X X X X X X X X LA_CROIX-HELLEAN X X
X X X X X X X X TORONTO X X
X X X X X X X X ONE_TWO_THREE X X
```

Comment: Decrementing `NF` is undefined behavior per POSIX so YMMV with using that. Some awks will remove the last field, some won't and some might produce an error message.

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks for pointing that out; I've never run into a problem with it so far. GNU awk and mawk delete the field, but OneTrueAwk allows the decrement but leaves the field vars populated (yet only prints the line to NF fields). Do you recall a specific dialect with which this might generate an error message? (I suppose one might work around the issue with a `$NF="";` before `NF--`. What are your thoughts on that?)

Comment: I haven't come across one that produces an error. In awks that don't delete the last field when you use `NF--`, doing `$NF=""` would cause the last FS in $0 to be replaced with an OFS and left there while in awks that do truncate with `NF--` that final OFS would be removed so it'd still make the script non-portable. You really need some variation of `sub(/[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+$/,"")` for portability (assuming the default FS of course) and that'd have the added benefit of not recompiling $0 and not changing all other FSs to OFSs.